# Chamar PROC MVC para exibir a lista de usuários que não conseguem se cadastrar

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, stored-procedures

Tentando chamar a PROC `sp_UsuariosVariasTentativasCadastro_Result`, que trás uma lista de acordo com os dados do formulário. Mas não está acontecendo nada. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

> OBS: criei todas essa "camadas" mas não sei se tem a necessidade.

**BLL**

```
public class ListUserBLL: BaseBLL
{
    public List<Usuario> ListarLogUser(int pagina = 0, int linhas = 0)
    {
        if (linhas == 0)
            linhas = int.MaxValue;

        return banco.Usuario
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.FgAtivo == 0)
            .OrderBy(x => x.DsNome)
            .Skip(pagina * linhas)
            .Take(linhas)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ListUserController : Controller
{
    public ListUserModel db = new ListUserModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new ListUserModel())
        {
            // var data = context.Usuario.SqlQuery<>
            var data = context.DsNome.SqlQuery<Usuario>("exec sp_UsuariosVariasTentativasCadastro_Result").ToList();

            return View(data);
        }          
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
@model IEnumerable

@{ ViewBag.Title = "ListUser"; Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-head">
        <h3 class="box-title">Cadastros não realizados</h3>
        <h6>Lista de usuários que não realizou cadastrado</h6>
        <h6>Quantidade de usuários: @(Model != null && Model.logUser != null ? Model.logUser.Count : 0)</h6>
        <div class="msg  w3-margin-top"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content table-responsive no-padding">
        @if (Model != null) 
        { 
            if (Model.logUser.Count > 0) 
            {
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="w3-light-grey">
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Celular</th>
                            <th>Endereço</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.logUser) 
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.DsEmail</td>
                            <td>@item.DsNome</td>
                            <td>@item.DsCelular</td>
                            <td>@item.DsEnderecoCompleto</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            } 
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class ListUserModel
{
    public string DsEmail { get; set; }
    public string DsNome { get; set; }
    public string DsCelular { get; set; }
    public string DsEnderecoCompleto { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class ListUserViewModel
{
    public List<sp_UsuariosVariasTentativasCadastro_Result> logUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: mas você debugou pra ver os parâmetros? porque com `linhas=0` não vai trazer nada por causa do `Take()`. Tenta remover o skip/take e faz um teste e veja se retorna, depois remove o where, pra ter certeza que a proc retorna

Comment: Não funcionou... ele não tá encontrando minha View tbm, não sei o pq...

Comment: executando a proc fora do programa, no *management studio* por exemplo funciona?

Comment: @RicardoPontual funciona, ela trás a lista certinho.

Comment: se você está no mesmo banco, executou a proc com os mesmos parâmetros deve retornar igual. A proc não tem parâmetros certo? Então `banco.Usuario.AsNoTracking().ToList()` deve retornar tudo

Comment: Pior que não tá rodando por causa da miha controller.. tem algo errado nela...

Comment: Pode colocar a SP e a classe `Usuario` na sua questão? O problema poderá estar aí.

Comment: @JoãoMartins, posso sim !

Comment: @JoãoMartins , é que eu preciso chamar uma lista de usuários que não conseguem se cadastrar, e essa lista vem nessa procedure que estou tentando chamar.